# Using Heroku as the primary Git Repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, github

Are there are any drawbacks of using Heroku as the primary Git repo - as a replacement for Github ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku isn't a replacement for GitHub (and certainly don't have all the *social* feature, pull request, fork queues, reviews and comments on commits...).
Plus I don't think it [supports smart http](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support) (which is important when you are pushing behind an enterprise firewall).
And it [doesn't support submodules](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules) ([GitHub does](http://help.github.com/submodules/))

But it is adapted for managing and deploying web application, and has [advanced monitoring feature](http://www.heroku.com/how/observe). If it is your case, then Heroku is the right choice.